# How to fulfill open graph requirements for buit-in read action

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

I want to know how to give user ability to turn off action sharing on timeline when they want as Facebook wants this feature to be implemented before actions can be submitted. I have browsed some relating questions but haven't found any solution.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following doc describes how you can delete already published actions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#delete

Comment: yes but what about "give user ability to turn off action sharing "